# I want to modify the default values of a category template from a content script in Groovy within OpenText

Tags: groovy, content-script, opentext

I want to modify the default values of a category template from a content script in Groovy within OpenText. Within one of the attributes of the category template, I want to append the current year. To define the current year, I'm using the following Java library:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
String currentYear = sdf.format(new Date());
log.error("${sdf.format(date)}")
```

How can I achieve this in Groovy within an OpenText environment? Specifically, how can I programmatically update the default values of a category template attribute to include the current year?